# How am I supposed to time my press when trying to do the Roll Recovery?

Tags: assassins-creed-unity

The `Roll Recovery` ability says the following:

> Roll Recovery will reduce the damage you take when jumping from a high ledge.  Press [Interact] when near the ground to perform.

What do they mean by "near the ground?" Does this mean before 1 second before landing? Just before I hit the ground? The moment I hit the ground? The moment I hear the thud of my landing? When I see the animation of Arno kneeling down?

I've tried tapping at all sorts of timings and could not do the roll.  Is there a trick to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found that it's not quite "midway". It seems to be consistently at a specific height from the ground (provided you've jumped down from a higher height). You should press when your feet are at about standing height away from the ground, no matter what height you are jumping from.

I'm not sure how many seconds this qualifies for, it's certainly less than a second but much more than right at landing. Just press based on how far away you are from the ground, this seems to work out the best consistently.

---

If you can't nail the timing perfectly, don't feel bad. Fortunately the game is very forgiving about the timing.  Rather than trying to figure out when exactly to press, you can actually just spam the button before you touch ground.  You're not penalized for mis-timing it.

It doesn't necessarily have to be at a very high height either, any jump from at least waist high you should be able to roll.

Answer (score 1):

> **Roll Recovery**
>
> How to Unlock: This skill costs 2 points and is unlocked
> by completing Sequence 02.
>
> Arno has increased recovery time after
> falling from a height and takes reduced damage. You need to press
> <kbd>**Circle**</kbd>/<kbd>**B**</kbd> when falling to perform this move.

For you to perform this move you can go at it 2 ways. Train on rooftops and ....practice your timing and just press <kbd>**Circle**</kbd>/<kbd>**B**</kbd> when you are about midway to the ground. (I've found this works for me).

If you don't have the patience to go out and practice just spam <kbd>**Circle**</kbd>/<kbd>**B**</kbd> while falling and the roll will be performed.

Comment: I think I've figured out the timing. It seems to be based on how far away you are from the ground. At about standing height to be precise. So we really shouldn't be counting the time it takes to fall, but the height we are at.

Comment: I usually press around midway and I roll everytime.

Comment: But that wouldn't quite work if you are jumping at a very high place (like say 3 stories up). Midway would be too soon I think and have not been able to do the roll at that height.

Comment: It works because I say midway but your brain coordination with sight and action of your figure is always a bit delayed to the exact midway height. So i tend to keep that in mind and I never fail. It was just a practice thing for me.